# Delete Cache Of Browsers With VB6

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, caching, browser, vb6

I want to delete browsers caches ( History , Cookies , Temp Dir , saved Passwords and Form Data ) with **VB6** ( Visual basic : version 6 )

if i know where those stored in my PC i can do it . ( or commands example : Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255"    to delete IE caches )

i want to know those places .
Firefox , Opera , Google Chrome caches files storage or commands to delete them !

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are the default values for Windows XP/2000, note that some path are modifiable

Firefox:

```
%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxx
```

with *xxx* as a random string folder

Chrome:

```
%AppData%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache
```

Opera

```
%AppData%\Local\Opera\Opera\cache
```

you can find this last one if you go in Opera to the menu and then Help -> About Opera

Hope this helps

Comment: and i must delete these folders ?  i know that passwords are storage with name : wand.dat (opera) , web data (GC) , key3.dat + signons.sqlite ( Firefox) .  But i want to know orther caches file like History , Temp directory of all browsers  and etec ! just those  files and delete them ! i don't want to delete all caches folder !